# Python: I can't import a module even though it's in site-packages

Tags: python, module, installation, package

I'm following the tutorial "Think Python" and I'm supposed to install the package called swampy. I'm running python 2.7.3 although I also have python 3 installed. I extracted the package and placed it in site-packages:
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\swampy-2.1.1
C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\swampy-2.1.1
But when i try to import a module from it within python:

```
import swampy.TurtleWorld
```

I just get no module named swampy.TurtleWorld.
I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out, here's a link to the lesson if that helps:
http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython005.html

Comment: Does `import swampy` work?

Comment: no I get "no module named swampy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I extracted the package and placed it in site-packages:

No, that's the wrong way of "installing" a package. Python packages come with a `setup.py` script that should be used to install them. Simply do:

```
python setup.py install
```

And the module will be installed correctly in the site-packages of the python interpreter you are using. If you want to install it for a specific python version use `python2`/`python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it man, I was completely roadblocked by my inability to install a package.

Comment: @neuroblade As a side note, you probably want to give a look at [`easy_install`](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html) and [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/), two package managers for python. Then you will be able, for example, to install `swampy` with a simple `easy_install swampy` at the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is having trouble with this on Windows, I just added my sites-package directory to my PATH variable and it worked like any normal module import.

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in PyCharm where I could see the modules I wanted in site-packages which is located in lib but it wouldn't recognize them. Here's how I fixed it and hopefully this can be transferable to other IDE's.

First solution: When you start a new project you needed to click "Inherit global site-packages" and it will work.

Second solution: When you start a project you cant click that box anywhere but you can go into settings -> project -> python interpreter and in there you can install individually all the packages you need.

Hopefully this helps.